# php json_encode response sends back html to ajax jquery request instead json

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, wordpress

for a simple contact form as wordpress plugin, i've created a form  as a popup in same page:

```
<form method="post" id="w_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <label for="first_name" class="text-secondary">First Name</label>
    <input id="first_name" type="text" name="first_name"  form-control" value="" required="">

    <label for="last_name" class="text-secondary">Last Name</label>
    <input id="last_name" type="text" name="last_name" form-control" value="" required="">


    <button class="btn btn-danger" id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
        Submit
    </button>

</form>
```

and its data will send to backend by ajax:

```
$("#w_form").submit( function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({

        type: "post",
        data: new FormData(this),
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        beforeSend: function() {

            $('#submit').attr("disabled", "disabled");

        },
        success: function( response ) {

           alert( response );

           // if ( response.status == 1 ) {

           //    $('#w_form')[0].reset();

           // }


        },
        error: function (xhr, error) {

            console.debug(xhr);

            console.debug(error);

        },

    });

});
```

that passes to php code in the same page and the top of the form:

```
if ( isset( $_POST['first_name'] ) ) {

    $uploaded_status;

    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name  = $_POST['last_name'];

    $to = 'abc@example.com';
    $subject = 'test';
    $body = 'body';


    if ( wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, '') ) {

        $uploaded_status = 1;

    } else {

        $uploaded_status = 0;

    }

    if ( $uploaded_status == 1 ) {

        $response = array();

        $response['status']  = 1;

        $response['message'] = 'Your form submitted successfully!';

        header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8", true);

        echo json_encode($response);

    }

}
```

this process works correctly and sends form's data by email to email address, but the response data as `:success` part of ajax, gets html content instead json and returns `parsererror` as `console.debug(error);`

so as i mentioned, the submission and sending data as email, works correctly but i have no correct data for the respond process to control UI after submitted button

Comment: to clarify: You send the ajax request to the same page and receive HTML output as part of the response - thus invalidating json response data?

Comment: @RamRaider yes, i send form data as ajax to backend and it uses that data to send email, it works correct so far, but after success passing ajax, it couldnt get response as json so hasnt correct data

Answer (score 1):

If you are receiving invalid JSON data in response to an Ajax request sent to the same page you need to discard any output buffer prior to sending the response and then terminate processing immediately afterwards to prevent any further content being appended to the response stream.

```
if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' &&  isset( $_POST['first_name'],$_POST['last_name'] ){

    ob_clean();# discard any previous buffer data

    $uploaded_status;

    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name  = $_POST['last_name'];

    $to = 'abc@example.com';
    $subject = 'test';
    $body = 'body';


    if ( wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, '') ) {
        $uploaded_status = 1;
    } else {
        $uploaded_status = 0;
    }

    if ( $uploaded_status == 1 ) {
        $response = array();
        $response['status']  = 1;
        $response['message'] = 'Your form submitted successfully!';


        header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8", true);
        exit( json_encode( $response ) );#terminate
    }
}
```

Comment: what can you observe in the console when you receive the ajax response?

Comment: i used ```            error: function (xhr, error) {

                console.debug(xhr);

                console.debug(error);

            },
``` to check error that fires `parsererror`

Comment: when i remove `dataType: 'json',` in jquery section, wont have error although we set json_encode( $response ) as php output, the ajax response is an html without $response

Comment: i think the main point is pass data from php to jquey. php does main duty correctly (sending email), but to pass $respone we have problem, so in this step there isnt any output

Comment: i guess since the first output of php is sending email as html, althought i pass json_encode after that, ajax gets html as responce

Comment: you could try with another `ob_clean();` before `header("Content-Type:...`